# sorting an NSMutableArray of objects (strings & objects)

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I'm having trouble sorting one of my NSMutableArrays.

The array is set up as follows

```
classesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];

NSMutableArray *tmpClassMembers = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil] autorelease];
//tmpClassMembers gets populated

//hold an array with the class ID, name and class members.
//classID and classname are just strings essentially
NSMutableArray *tmpClass = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:msClass.ClassId,msClass.ClassName,tmpClassMembers,nil];

//add the new class to the main class array
[classesArray addObject:tmpClass];
```

An example order is (these are stored in element[1] in the array (the className)

```
classesArray[0][1] = "3. Science 5B"
classesArray[1][1] = "4. Geography 6S"
classesArray[2][1] = "2. Biology 6T"
classesArray[3][1] = "1. English 1A"
```

I have tried using a block sort, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I'm expecting it to sort based on the second element ([1]) in the array. This should be the classes name.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [classesArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
        NSString *numA = [a objectAtIndex:1]; //eg: "1. English 1A"
        NSString *numB = [b objectAtIndex:1]; //eg: "3. Science 5B
        //NSLog(@"a=%@, b=%@", numA, numB);
        return [numB compare:numA];
    }];
```

I am expecting the classesArray to be in the following order

```
classesArray[0][1] = "1. English 1A"
classesArray[1][1] = "2. Biology 6T"
classesArray[2][1] = "3. Science 5B"
classesArray[3][1] = "4. Geography 6S"
```

So basically it should sort on the string - surely it would see that each one starts with a number and then sorts on that?

I cannot get the number as the ID to sort as the id is actually something like DF345345-ERERT56 and bares no relevance whatsoever.

Where am I going wrong?!

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: And why would English sort before Biology?  (Do an NSLog of your entire array, before and after sorting, and append the copy/pasted output to you question.)

Comment: @HotLicks The numbers at the start are part of his strings. His strings literally go `"1. xxxx"`, `"2. xxxx"` and so on.

Comment: English should sort by its number, eg 1. The post changed my example and remembered it. I've done an nslog and the array is the same before and after the sort operation

Comment: The array does not change. `sortedArray` is a *different* array.

Comment: Post your actual input values and the actual result (and what you desire).

Comment: @matt - I was thinking that. I tried setting the sorted array back to the classArray but had issues with NSArray & NSMutableArrays. How do I then get the sorted array back to my ClassesArray??

Comment: `copy` to make an NSArray. `mutableCopy` to make an NSMutableArray.

Comment: @matt - that's one interpretation.  But he uses the same numbering with different names a few lines up.

Comment: @MattFacer -- Do the NSLogs and COPY THEM INTO YOUR QUESTION.  It's axiomatic that you're imperfectly describing the data, and a picture is worth a thousand words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use the tmpClasses array. If you make a Class called MyClass with properties of the variables:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString* classID;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString* className; 
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray* classMembers;
```

Then you can use this method to sort an array of MyClass objects:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"classID"
                                             ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
arrayOfMyClassObjects = [arrayOfMyClassObjects sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: although the question was closed, this prompted me to make the array in to a class which now can be sorted on the "className" property as suggested.